# Nginx setting, url parameters been igonred

Tags: nginx

i have an proxy to vue project setting like blow

```
location /web/ {
    proxy_pass http://{domain}/;
}
```

but when i send {proxydomain}/web/login?aa=1&bb=2 it return as {proxydomain}/web/login
ignore the url pamrams

and if I using

```
location /web/ {
    proxy_pass http://{domain}/$request_uri;
}
```

somehow when i access {proxydomain}/web/login?aa=1&bb=2 it will return with 502(bad getway) error.

does anyone know solution?

Answer (score 0):

According the [documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20111119030118/http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_pass):

You could use teh regex location

```
location ~* ^/web/(.*) {
  proxy_pass http://{domain}/$uri$is_args$args;;
}
```

Comment: In this case, my proxyed webside's js and css file's content-type all became text/html
and console shows error in js file
```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```